# Mysql : list only not null values using case

Tags: mysql, case

I'm trying to list only the NOT NULL values using the query :

```
SELECT 
        firm.ShortName AS companyshortname,
        firm.ExtRefId AS compextrefid,
        finrnd.dealDate AS dealdate,
        (CASE
            WHEN (ent.EntityType = 'Firm') THEN afirm.ShortName
            WHEN (ent.EntityType = 'Partnership') THEN pship.ShortName
            WHEN
                (ent.EntityType = 'Individual')
            THEN
                CONCAT(ind.LastName,
                        ', ',
                        ind.FirstName)
        END) AS investor,
        (CASE
            WHEN (ent.EntityType = 'Firm' AND afirm.ExtRefId IS NOT NULL)  THEN afirm.ExtRefId
            WHEN (ent.EntityType = 'Partnership' AND pship.ExtRefId IS NOT NULL) THEN pship.ExtRefId
            WHEN (ent.EntityType = 'Individual' AND ind.ExtRefId IS NOT NULL) THEN ind.ExtRefId
        END) AS investorextrefid,
         finrndinv.isLeadInvestor AS isleadinvestor
    FROM
        ((((((financinginvestors finrndinv
        JOIN financingrounds finrnd ON ((finrnd.financingid = finrndinv.financingid)))
        JOIN firms firm ON ((firm.FirmEntID = finrnd.compentid)))
        LEFT JOIN entities ent ON ((ent.InvEntID = finrndinv.investorid)))
        LEFT JOIN firms afirm ON ((afirm.FirmEntID = ent.InvEntID)))
        LEFT JOIN individuals ind ON ((ind.IndEntID = ent.InvEntID)))
        LEFT JOIN partnerships pship ON ((pship.PShipEntID = ent.InvEntID)));
```

But on running the code I do get values that are NULL for the column named `investorextrefid`. I'm not sure if the condition that I've added inside the WHEN clause inside the CASE is the right approach. This query gives the same result as without the AND part inside the WHEN clause within the case.

```
+------------------+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+------------------+----------------+
| companyshortname | compextrefid | dealdate            | investor                         | investorextrefid | isleadinvestor |
+------------------+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+------------------+----------------+
| Access Insurance | ASP:143      | 2019-06-06 00:00:00 | ASP                              | NULL             |              0 |
| Access Insurance | ASP:143      | 2019-06-06 00:00:00 | Russell 2000                     | NULL             |              0 |
| Access Insurance | ASP:143      | 2019-06-06 00:00:00 | Addiko Bank                      | ASP:62           |              0 |
| Access Insurance | ASP:143      | 2019-06-06 00:00:00 | Universal American Financial Cor | ASP:119          |              0 |
| Access Insurance | ASP:143      | 2019-06-06 00:00:00 | Lever, Inc                       | ASP:131          |              1 |
+------------------+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: You do not have an ELSE coded in your CASE function. So, if there are any values such that none of the 3 WHEN conditions are true, investorextrefid will be set to NULL.

Comment: Try adding: `ELSE CONCAT(ent.EntityType, '', IF(ISNULL(ind.ExtRefId), 'NULL', ind.ExtRefId))` to see what the ELSE situation is.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson thanks for the response, what I was thinking was how do I even exclude the row itself if it was null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get the NULL values is because you do not have an `ELSE` case

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

```
CASE
    WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
    [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list] END CASE
```

So if you want to replace NULL values in the result set when none of your conditions is satisfied 
you should just add and `ELSE` case:

```
...
WHEN (ent.EntityType = 'Individual' AND ind.ExtRefId IS NOT NULL) THEN ind.ExtRefId 
ELSE 'Some other value' 
END) AS investorextrefid,
...
```

If on the other hand you want to ommit these rows entirely you should just put a WHERE condition in the end of your query like this :

```
WHERE 
(ent.EntityType = 'Firm' AND afirm.ExtRefId IS NOT NULL) 
OR (ent.EntityType = 'Partnership' AND pship.ExtRefId IS NOT NULL) 
OR (ent.EntityType = 'Individual' AND ind.ExtRefId IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of this? thanks for the response, it worked. :)